# List type in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, types

```
type([1, 2]) is list - ok
type(list()) is list - ok
type(list) is type wtf?
```

Why type of list is type?
a try this in shell: >>> list and a get <class 'list'>

Comment: `list` is *not a list*. It is *the class* of lists. It is a `type`. All classes are objects, instances of `type` (or of derived metaclasses). So just like: `class Foo: pass` then `type(Foo)` vs `type(Foo())`

Comment: Types and classes are the same thing in Python.

Comment: As an analogy, the word "Animal" is not an animal, it's a word.